# I need to print data in 4 position of page properly but in my 3 and 4 position data is coming as inverted im using printhandler in c# and coordinates

Tags: c#, printing

```cs
case "VALIDITYFROM":
    if (printDataViewModel.nPrintType != 1)
    {
        string validFrom = printDataViewModel.ValidTo.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        nCurX = nPageLeft + float.Parse(dsItemCordinate.Tables\[0\].Rows\[nNewIndex\]\["X"\].ToString().Trim());
        nCurY = nPageTop + float.Parse(dsItemCordinate.Tables\[0\].Rows\[nNewIndex\]\["Y"\].ToString().Trim());
        nWidth = Convert.ToSingle(dsItemCordinate.Tables\[0\].Rows\[nNewIndex\]\["W"\].ToString().Trim());
        nHeight = Convert.ToSingle(dsItemCordinate.Tables\[0\].Rows\[nNewIndex\]\["H"\].ToString().Trim());

        drawRect = new RectangleF(nCurX, nCurY, nWidth, nHeight);
        drawFormat = new StringFormat
        {
            Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
        };
    
        S_LINE = validFrom;
    
        args.Graphics.DrawString(S_LINE, pFont3, Brushes.Black, drawRect, drawFormat);
    
        if(Slno == 3)
        {
            //string validFrom = printDataViewModel.ValidTo.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            nCurX = 100;//nPageLeft + float.Parse(dsItemCordinate.Tables[0].Rows[nNewIndex]["X"].ToString().Trim());
            nCurY = 100;//nPageTop + float.Parse(dsItemCordinate.Tables[0].Rows[nNewIndex]["Y"].ToString().Trim());
            nWidth = Convert.ToSingle(dsItemCordinate.Tables[0].Rows[nNewIndex]["W"].ToString().Trim());
            nHeight = Convert.ToSingle(dsItemCordinate.Tables[0].Rows[nNewIndex]["H"].ToString().Trim());
    
            drawRect = new RectangleF(nCurX, nCurY, nWidth, nHeight);
            drawFormat = new StringFormat
            {
                Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
            };
    
            S_LINE = validFrom;
    
            args.Graphics.DrawString(S_LINE, pFont3, Brushes.Black, drawRect, drawFormat);
        }
    }
    break;
```

I tried with changing coordinates.

I need to print that date in 3 and 4 position of starigt without inverted